# How to limit the number of lines in UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a UITextView in my screen, the user should fill only **two lines**, and when the user in the second line the return key should turn into **Done**.

How can I limit the number of **lines** in UITextView? 
I searched a lot, and no results was useful!

I found this answer for Swift:

```
locationNoteTextView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 2
self.locationNoteTextView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByClipping
```

It didn't work, by this way the user can enter infinity character, but what viewed on the screen are just two lines!

So if you tried to print the text of textView you will find a disaster text.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to implement `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:`. This method is called whenever the text is going to change. You can access the current content of the text view using its text property.

Construct the new content from the passed range and replacement text with `[textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:replacementText]`.

You can then count the number of lines and return `YES` to allow the change or `NO` to reject it.

**EDIT:** On OP request:

**Swift:**

```
func sizeOfString (string: String, constrainedToWidth width: Double, font: UIFont) -> CGSize {
    return (string as NSString).boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width: width, height: DBL_MAX),
        options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin,
        attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font],
        context: nil).size
}


func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let newText = (textView.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: text)
    var textWidth = CGRectGetWidth(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(textView.frame, textView.textContainerInset))
    textWidth -= 2.0 * textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding;

    let boundingRect = sizeOfString(newText, constrainedToWidth: Double(textWidth), font: textView.font!)
    let numberOfLines = boundingRect.height / textView.font!.lineHeight;

    return numberOfLines <= 2;
}
```

**Obj-C**

```
- (CGSize) sizeOfString:(NSString*)str constrainedToWidth:(CGFloat)width andFont:(UIFont*)font
{
    return [str boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, DBL_MAX)
                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                           attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}
                              context:nil].size;
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSString *newText = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
    CGFloat textWidth = CGRectGetWidth(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(textView.frame, textView.textContainerInset));
    textWidth -= 2.0 * textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding;
    CGSize boundingRect = [self sizeOfString:newText constrainedToWidth:textWidth andFont:textView.font];
    int numberOfLines = boundingRect.height / textView.font.lineHeight;
    return numberOfLines <= 2;
}
```

Comment: where is the limiting of lines in your answer?!

Comment: thank you, but can you explain more please?
 I didn't understand how 
[textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:replacementText]
can help me?

Comment: @Abhinav The question is tagged "swift", so it would be better to provide your answer in Swift. Thank you.

Comment: Added a swift version. Disclaimer: I just quickly converted it into Swift, didn't get chance to test so please bear with me. Thanks for pointing :) @EricD.

Comment: #1 If you add a space as last character you are able to keep adding spaces. #2 If you reach the limit and then press the space key twice, the textview even adds an additional line. Anybody have any suggestions to avoid that behavior?

Answer (score 19):

For iOS 7+

```
textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 10;
textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

OR

```
textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 10;
[textView.layoutManager textContainerChangedGeometry:textView.textContainer];
```

Comment: This is buggy. It allows you to hit return past the end of the text view and then your cursor disappears and you have to hit delete to find it again.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone wants realtime line number count, this is how you do it with RxSwift & RxCocoa

```
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    textView.rx_text.asDriver().driveNext { text in

        let text = text as NSString

        var textWidth: CGFloat = CGRectGetWidth(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(self.textView.frame, self.textView.textContainerInset))

        textWidth -= 2.0 * self.textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding

        let textAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: “Set your font here”, size: 26.0)!]

        let boundingRect: CGRect = text.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(textWidth, 0), options: [NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading], attributes: textAttributes, context: nil)

        let font = UIFont(name: “Set your font here”, size: 26.0)

        guard let lineHeight = font?.lineHeight else {return}

        let numberOfLines = CGRectGetHeight(boundingRect) / lineHeight

        if numberOfLines <= 2 {


            self.textView.typingAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: “Set your font here”, size: 26.0)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: “Set your color here”]

        } else {

            self.textView.typingAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: “Set your font here”, size: 18.0)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: “Set your color here”]

        }

    }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated @Abhinav code to Swift 5, also added support to limit char count.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet private var textView: UITextView!

    private let maxNumberOfLines = 4
    private let maxCharactersCount = 100

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
    private func textView(_ textView: UITextView, newText: String, underLineLimit: Int) -> Bool {
        guard let textViewFont = textView.font else {
            return false
        }

        let rect = textView.frame.inset(by: textView.textContainerInset)
        let textWidth = rect.width - 2.0 * textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding

        let boundingRect = newText.size(constrainedToWidth: textWidth,
                                        font: textViewFont)

        let numberOfLines = boundingRect.height / textViewFont.lineHeight

        let underLimit = Int(numberOfLines) <= underLineLimit
        return underLimit
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView,
                  shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange,
                  replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

        let newText = textView.text.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)

        let underLineLimit = self.textView(textView, newText: newText, underLineLimit: maxNumberOfLines)
        let underCharacterLimit = newText.count <= maxCharactersCount
        return underLineLimit && underCharacterLimit
    }
}

extension String {
    func replacingCharacters(in range: NSRange, with string: String) -> String {
        let currentNSString = self as NSString
        return currentNSString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    }

    func size(constrainedToWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGSize {
        let nsString = self as NSString
        let boundingSize = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        return nsString
            .boundingRect(with: boundingSize,
                          options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                          attributes: [.font: font],
                          context: nil)
            .size
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is @Abhinav answer but in **Swift**

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {


    let newText = (textView.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: text)

    let textAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: textView.font]

    var textWidth: CGFloat = CGRectGetWidth(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(textView.frame, textView.textContainerInset))

    textWidth -= 2.0 * textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding

    let boundingRect: CGRect = newText.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(textWidth, 0), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading, attributes: textAttributes, context: nil)

  var numberOfLines = CGRectGetHeight(boundingRect) / textView.font.lineHeight;

    return numberOfLines <= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is @Abhinav's answer updated for **Swift 3**

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    guard maxLines > 0 else {
        return true
    }

    let newText = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)

    let textAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font : textView.font!]

    var textWidth: CGFloat = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(textView.frame, textView.textContainerInset).width

    textWidth -= 2.0 * textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding

    let boundingRect: CGRect = newText.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: textWidth, height: 0), options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], attributes: textAttributes, context: nil)

    let numberOfLines = Int(floor(boundingRect.height / textView.font!.lineHeight))

    return numberOfLines <= maxLines

}
```

Where **maxLines** is the number of lines you want to limit the textView to. If it's 0 then unlimited number of lines.

Answer (score -3):

Find below the Objective C version of Abhinav's answer:

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSString *newText = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
    CGFloat textWidth = CGRectGetWidth(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(textView.frame, textView.textContainerInset));
    textWidth -= 2.0 * textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding;

    CGSize boundingRect = [self sizeOfString:newText constrainedToWidth:textWidth font:textView.font];
    NSInteger numberOfLines = boundingRect.height / textView.font.lineHeight;

    return numberOfLines <= 2;
}

-(CGSize)sizeOfString:(NSString *)string constrainedToWidth:(double)width font:(UIFont *)font
{
    return  [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, DBL_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font} context:nil].size;
}
```